# How to get Project directory path in "build.xml", "pom.xml"?

Tags: xml, maven, pom.xml, build.xml

In JAVA if I type, it will give project directory path.

```
public class TestProjectPath {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

    }

}
```

I can append path that I got from above code to the path of files that would need my project for example properties file.
This helps in making my project independent of location, suppose I move it from `C: drive` to `D: drive` , it will work.
I want to do same in `build.xml` and `pom.xml`, how can I do that?

Comment: For maven, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460525/what-is-the-maven-base-directory
For ant, it's "${basedir}"

Comment: If you are talking about property files you should go a different way via `this.getResourceAsStream("/property.file")`. Furthermore i would suggest to make the decision to go with Maven or got with Ant but not with both.